# How do I configure a Rails app to use just Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use Resque in a Ruby on Rails application. I have no need for a relational database nor do I plan to store anything. I just want to use Resque.

How do I configure this application?

I did this:

Empty config/database.yml

In config/application.rb

```
#require 'rails/all'
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

And removed the < ActiveRecord::Base in my models.

But I get errors here:

```
class ProjectController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @project = Project.new
  end
end

=simple_form_for @project do |f|
    =f.input :scene, :label => 'Scene'
    =f.submit

ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `model_name' for Project:Class
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't the Project-class an ActiveRecord-class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your model inherit from [ActiveResource::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveResource/Base.html) instead:

```
class Project < ActiveResource::Base
  # ...
end
```

That will provide the methods required by helpers such as `form_for` without the need to use ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need rails you don't need to use rails.

You can simply gem install resque and use a different web application framework.

I recommend looking at  Sinatra, or Camping.

http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro

https://github.com/camping/camping

EDIT: Resque already comes with a full functioning Sinatra app that may suit your needs.

Comment: Alternatively you could use an empty sqllite db.

Comment: I'll probably switch to Sinatra, just for the sake of practising :)

Answer (score 0):

If you no need to use full Rails stack, use Sinatra. I like the [Resque way](http://blog.redistogo.com/2010/10/04/resque-with-sinatra/) to connect to Redis. I do not suggest you to use queues, just storage from here:  **Resque.redis.rpush**